# A question regarding the syntax of loop in C

Tags: c

I saw this little problem in the practice book, which is used to print whatever is typed in backward. And here, I just can't understand this loop `for (; i >= 0; i--)`, why doesn't it assign the `i` to a variable in the first, is this a normal syntax as well? Thanks!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    int i;
    char msg[25];
    printf("Type up to 25 characters and then press Enter...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        msg[i] = getchar(); //Outputs a single character
        if (msg[i] == '\n') {
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n'); // One line break after the loop is done.
    for (; i >= 0; i--) {   // <--- this is the line
        putchar(msg[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Indent your code so that we (and you) can read it.

Comment: Why do an assignment if it already has the value you want?

Comment: Note that the loop you're curious about is effectively redoing the loop before it, but backwards.  So, it makes sense to start at the end of the first loop, right? ;P

Answer (score 5):

> why doesn't it assign the i to a variable in the first

Because `i` already has the value we want to start at, from prior logic.

> is this a normal syntax as well?

Yes. Any of the three parts of the `for` intro may be empty.

Comment: The answers are correct, but regarding *Because i already has the value we want to start at, from prior logic.*... I'm afraid the program's logic is broken in many ways.

Comment: Didn't claim otherwise but this isn't CodeReview.SE

Comment: If any can be empty then all can too

Answer (score 0):

The three expressions which appear between the parentheses in a `for()` loop are all optional, and theoretically arbitrary.

Theoretically, you could write

```
for(a = b; c < d; e++)
    printf("%d\n", f);
```

This is probably meaningless and useless, but as far as the C language is concerned, there's nothing wrong with it, and I wouldn't expect a compiler to emit any error messages or even warnings about it.

Now, *conventionally*, the first expression initializes something, the second expression tests whether we should make another trip through the loop, and the third expression increments.  But that's all by convention, and again, all three expressions are optional.

For example, you could write

```
int i = 5;
for(; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

In this case, `i` gets its initial value when it's declared.  This looks weird, to be sure, and it's arguably bad style, but it's not illegal.

The other expressions are optional, too.  For example, I could write it like this:

```
int i = 5;
for(; i < 10; )
    printf("%d\n", i++);
```

Now `i` gets incremented within the `printf` call, so there's no need to increment it in the `for` loop header.  But by now, we've basically got a `while` loop:

```
int i = 5;
while(i < 10)
    printf("%d\n", i++);
```

Anyway, this explains the loop you saw.  The variable `i` already had the value it needed, from code up above, so there was no reason to set it in the `for` loop header.

Answer (score 0):

The initial clause of the `for` loop can be empty: in the case you mention, `i` already contains the number of characters stored into the array, 25 or less if the user typed fewer characters before the newline. Yet the program has a bug because `i` should be decremented to avoid accessing `msg` beyond the last character stored in the array. Decrementing `i` if the character typed was `'\n'` is inconsistent and starting the output at `msg[i]` is incorrect too.

Your *practice book* is obsolete and confusing. Consider discarding it and using a more up to date book or online tutorial.

Any of the clauses of the `for` loop can be empty:

- the initial clause may not be needed
- the test clause can be empty, causing an infinite loop that ends either via a `break` or a `return` statement, or via a direct or indirect call to `exit()`.
- the update clause can contain any update expression, or nothing if the code already updates the required variables in the body of the loop, if any update is needed at all.

The first `for` loop is a very idiomatic example: `for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) { ... }`

Here is another classic `for` loop: `for (;;) { /* repeat some action for ever */ }`

Note the following problems in the posted code:

- `main` must be defined with a return type `int`. The code uses an obsolete syntax where the return type was implicitly `int`. This syntax is invalid in C99.
- the first `for` loop stores up to 25 bytes to the array, if the user typed more than 24 characters before the newline or signalled an end of file before the newline.
- the program has undefined behavior in this latter case because `msg[i]` points beyond the end of `msg` if the user typed 25 characters before the newline.
- the contents of the array is printed backwards, with potentially some funny characters such as `ÿ` at the beginning if indeed the input was ended prematurely.
- there is no need to include `<string.h>`
- the parentheses around the return value `(0)` are useless.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, c;
    char msg[25];
    printf("Type up to 25 characters and then press Enter...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;
        msg[i] = c;
    }
    putchar('\n'); // One line break after the loop is done.
    while (--i >= 0) {   // equivalent to for (; --i >= 0;)
        putchar(msg[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My practice book is one of the best according to both Internet and Amazon, but maybe not after I read all these comments. My knowledge toward C is still lacking at this moment, so would you mind elaborating why put c == EOF with c== '\n'? EOF means -1 as I just googled it, but I don't  see why it has to be with c=='\n'

Comment: @Mattmmmmm: `getchar()` returns the next byte from the standard input stream or the special negative value `EOF` if no byte could be read either because of end of file or input error. `EOF` is usually defined as `-1`, but the C Standard only specifies that it is negative. The test `if (c == EOF || c == '\n') break;` uses the `||` operator to combine 2 separate tests, the second being evaluated only if the first one fails. It is equivalent to `if (c == EOF) break;` followed by `if (c == '\n') break;` The effect is to stop the loop if no byte can be read or if the byte is the newline character.

Comment: @Mattmmmmm: There is no need to decrement `i` since the newline will not have been stored to the array and `i` will not have been incremented. It is considered risky to modify the loop index inside the body of the loop, and in this particular case it is a bug because at the end of the loop `i` is not the number of characters stored in the array. Its value is inconsistent depending on whether the user entered a newline in the first 25 characters or not.

Comment: @Mattmmmmm: can you confirm that the practice book is actually the C tutorial by Anakul Verma: https://anukulverma.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/c-tutorial-18-getch-putch-getchar-putchar/ ? The example is identical, although the code is not even properly indented. The explanations are approximate... not blatantly false, but not entirely true either. I wish I could point you to a better tutorial, but in the mean time, you should learn some good basics from this one.